# Toast message doesn't open

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

so I have a problem whenever I click on a button that is supposed opening a bootstrap toast it doesn't work and if i specify show in the toast class to show it without clicking on the button, the close button doesn't work and the toast doesn't close; here is the code:

HTML

```html
<button id="button1" class="btn btn-info">Click me!</button>

<div id="alert" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small class="text-muted">11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Hello, world! This is a toast message.
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button1').click(function() {
        $('#alert').show('fade');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please check js section of toast https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/#toastshow you need to use `element.toast()` to toggle it https://jsfiddle.net/naLgozj9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the javascript code . **change this line of code `$('#alert').show('fade');` to `$('.toast').toast('show');`**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    $('.toast').toast('show');
  });
});
```

working jsfiddle link [Bootstrap Tooltip](https://jsfiddle.net/raihanuddin2/9q6Ltd1n/3/)